# Can't share HP laserjet 500 on windows 2003 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, print-server

I added a HP laserjet 500 M551 to a windows 2003 R2 server, acting as a print server. I can print from the printserver, but I can not share it. It tells me "sharing is not supported for this type of printer".

I have tried the "HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PCL6" and the "HP LaserJet Enterprise 500 color M551 Printer Series PCL6 Print Driver (no Installer)" drivers with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you connecting to the printer?  I seem to recall that you get that message if you install it with "Add a Network printer" but not with "Add Local Printer / new TCP/IP port"

Comment: I am connection to the printer via network -> "Add a network printer". Because it is a network printer, not connected locally.

Comment: @charlesbridge you were  right ... I will explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was I was connectin the printer as a "Network printer" - which in my understanding was correct, since the printer was connected via tcp network. BUT my understanding was wrong. Since the printer server is to act as a spooler for this printer, the printer is considered "Local", even if it is not local in any general sense. So I reinstalled the printer als a "Local" printer, and then I could share it.